# MongoDB with Xamarin.Forms connecting db issue c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mono, xamarin.forms

I have the following:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

and at this last line I get this:

```
{System.EntryPointNotFoundException: mono_get_runtime_build_info
  at (wrapper managed-to-native)** System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation:mono_get_runtime_build_info ()
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_FrameworkDescription () [0x00000] in <faa8163a322d41a99fc85eb6d1c29040>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.GetPlatformString () [0x00000] in <077b2160c936411eb67f8073bdcbbe94>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00081] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].LazyInitValue () [0x00080] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0003a] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateClientDocument (System.String applicationName) [0x00015] in <077b2160c936411eb67f8073bdcbbe94>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer..ctor (System.String applicationName) [0x00006] in <077b2160c936411eb67f8073bdcbbe94>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnectionFactory..ctor (MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionSettings settings, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IStreamFactory streamFactory, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Events.IEventSubscriber eventSubscriber) [0x00040] in <077b2160c936411eb67f8073bdcbbe94>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.BuildCluster () [0x0002e] in <077b2160c936411eb67f8073bdcbbe94>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.CreateCluster (MongoDB.Driver.ClusterKey clusterKey) [0x000ad] in <42bdb488f5094fc1bb90030259d358c6>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.GetOrCreateCluster (MongoDB.Driver.ClusterKey clusterKey) [0x00021] in <42bdb488f5094fc1bb90030259d358c6>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor (MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <42bdb488f5094fc1bb90030259d358c6>:0 
  at .....ctor () [0x00025] in ...
```

I've tried connecting at this line:

```
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

without setting, with and without connection string but nothing... I'm able to add documents to the db using command prompt and db.movie.insert as described here 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm but when I try to connect using the C# driver is like if the server is not running.

Please help! and thanks

Comment: The library you try to use is for the full mono platform, it seems it's not compatible with Xamarin. Remember Xamarin is not a full mono implementation and has some limitations.

Comment: Also, is your server in "localhost"? Remember that "localhost" in that context means the portable device, not your computer...

Comment: Hi, I've changed this

Comment: Hi, I;ve changed this

settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);

for this

settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);

and still... Not sure about mono version, how can I check that??

Comment: And that will solve nothing as 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost.

Comment: so what do you suggest? and thanks for your answer

Comment: First, change totally your philosophy, accessing directly a remote database is not safe, anyone can decompile your app and use the server address/credentials to do anything he wants on the DB.

Comment: Im building a mobile app that will connect to a remote server as any other app, How would you suggest to approach that?

Comment: If you ask that question then you lack the knowledge to create such application. Usually you will create a service on the server, per example a RESTful service, and then you will comunicate with that service which will implement a security layer to validate the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ip of machine which is a host of your mongo db. But I'd recommend you to develop some server side code, for example using node js. Then send rest based requests to your node js app, and in node js, read and write from/to db. This is far better than what you're trying to accomplish here. Your approach puts your data at risk.